# MySQL STR_TO_DATE glitch?

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-date-functions

I'm running into a problem with MySQL's STR_TO_DATE function. For example, this code:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("Saturday October 23 2010 11:00 AM", "%W %M %d %Y %h:%m %p");
```

outputs this:

```
2010-00-23 11:00:00
```

Why is everything correct except the month? Is this an error in my syntax?

Comment: Does this happen for all october month? or try with some different month too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong modifier for minutes - use:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("Saturday October 23 2010 11:00 AM", "%W %M %d %Y %h:%i %p")
```

You specified `%m`, which was overwriting the `%M` value - [see the modifiers via the DATE_FORMAT documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).  That's why the month was coming out as zero - the modifier for minutes is `%i`.

Comment: Ah, I must've been using outdated documentation... thanks a bunch!